# How To Building Membership Database As POCO Class and navigate to its user table?

Tags: database, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, poco

can anyone help me out with this issue, i'm tying to use the Membership database's tables along with my own project database and i need to use some data from the user's table 
(get the username in the comments and his avatar) so my question is how i can build the membership's database as POCO class and if it's ok to make relations between my user's table and my comments table without effecting the functionality of asp.net membership ?